# Difficulties comparing local directory and remote directory using diff

Tags: ssh, diff

I've found several methods on here about how to accomplish this but I have run into a problem which exceeds my linux knowledge. I want to compare a local folder against a remote folder and write an "alert" to a file if they are not the same which will be checkec by my nagios server and let people know the directories are out of sync.

The situation.

I CAN diff an individual file:

```
diff -w /data/telescopedata/40in/shd/2016/test <(ssh astro 'cat /data/40in/shd/2016/test')
0a1
> line 1
```

It successfully returns the difference so ssh and data paths are all good.

I can list the remote directory like this:

```
ssh astro 'ls -l /data/40in/shd/2016'
```

Now if I try do the same and compare the directories I get this:

```
diff -w /data/telescopedata/40in/shd/2016 <(ssh astro ls -l '/data/40in/shd/2016')
```

It results in:

```
diff: /data/telescopedata/40in/shd/2016/63: No such file or directory
```

The /63 led me to read about named pipes and anonymous pipes which I think I understand.  However, I am not sure how to make my diff work. I could do this with rsync but I want to see if I can make it work with diff.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
diff -w /data/telescopedata/40in/shd/2016 <(ssh astro ls -l '/data/40in/shd/2016')
```

This is nonsense. You can't compare directory like this. The easiest way would be to use `sshfs` to mount your remote directory locally and compare them:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/cmp
sudo sshfs astro:/data/40in/shd/2016 /mnt/cmp
sudo diff -qrw /data/telescopedata/40in/shd/2016 /mnt/cmp
fusermount -u /tmp/cmp
```

It should do the job just fine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jakuje.The nonsense came from multiple upvoted entries on this site so you will forgive me for trying them.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion which worked after I sorted out the kinks of using sshfs in a virtual machine and I am able to run the diff. For the sake of anyone who reads this, would you mind correcting your reply (2nd and 3rd lines) to reflect the same name as the mount point, i.e. /tmp/tmp and not /mtn/cmp. Thanks very much for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

That sshfs is very cool but I don't have it, so here's another simple approach which doesn't involve any mounts etc:

```
mkdir /tmp/cmp
scp -pr astro:/data/40in/shd/2016 /tmp/cmp
diff -rw /data/telescopedata/40in/shd/2016 /tmp/cmp/2016
rm -rf /tmp/cmp
```

It might seem pretty heavy-handed to copy the entire directory tree across the network, but you're doing that somehow in any host-to-host comparison (except rsync, but it doesn't show you actual differences). However there is still the overhead of writing to disk.  Using `scp -C` compression option could speed things up if you have large text files.

Incidentally, note the -r on the diff.  Doing a plain diff on two directories only compares the top-level content of those directories, so may report they are identical even if contents of corresponding sub-directories differ.

Comment: I will certainly give it a try. I'm putting this in a script so I will do both and time them to see which is more efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## compare local & remote hierarchy

```
rsync -arnv --exclude 'pdf/' --exclude 'libs/' --exclude '*.gz'  root@127.129.156.177:$PWD .
```

## with alternate path

```
rsync -arnv --exclude 'pdf/' --exclude 'libs/' --exclude '*.gz'  root@127.129.156.177:${PWD/html/release}/ . | grep -v '/$'
```